# Json.NET backward compatibility: write new property name, but read either new or old property

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Lets assume I have like this property which I use to save/load settings:

```
public Options RectangleCaptureOptions { get; set; }
```

and I want to change property name to `RegionCaptureOptions` instead of `RectangleCaptureOptions`. But if I change name of property then [Json .NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) won't be able find it to deserialize.

Accepted answer here won't work:

[.NET NewtonSoft JSON deserialize map to a different property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915503/net-newtonsoft-json-deserialize-map-to-a-different-property-name)

Because if I use `JsonProperty`:

```
[JsonProperty("RectangleCaptureOptions")]
public Options RegionCaptureOptions { get; set; }
```

Then it will also serialize property as `RectangleCaptureOptions` which is old name.

So when I change name of variable or property still want to support old naming of them when deserializing (`RegionCaptureOptions` or `RectangleCaptureOptions` for this example) but use current name when serializing (`RegionCaptureOptions`). That way I can have backward compatibility support for my settings json file while loading (deserializing) them.

I think most clean solution would be making custom attribute such as `JsonAlternativeName` and using it like this:

```
[JsonAlternativeName("RectangleCaptureOptions")]
public Options RegionCaptureOptions { get; set; }
```

Optionally it can have multiple parameter support, that way you can add multiple alternative names.

But not sure how to accomplish it (or is it possible at all) and can't find similar solution in StackOverflow because in each questions I found, people suggests using `JsonProperty` which not helps in my case.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [json deserialize from legacy property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155458/json-deserialize-from-legacy-property-names).  But [Alternate property name while deserializing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792274/alternate-property-name-while-deserializing) is very close also