# JsonObjectContract.ParametrizedConstructor Marked as Obsolete and Has No Alternative

Tags: json.net

`JsonObjectContract.ParametrizedConstructor` is marked as Obsolete and says that `OverrideCreator` should be used instead. However `OverrideCreator` does not set `_parametrizedConstructor` or `_parameterizedCreator` meaning that if you need to set those values from the outside you must use `ParametrizedConstructor`.

Is this intentional? If so why?

Thanks!

Edit 1:

To explain why I'm asking, I have a class in my application that handles serialization (using JSON.Net). This class creates a custom `IContractResolver` (based on `DefaultContractResolver`) that has a stock set of `JsonConverter`s that I wrote for my application. This allows the contracts that are generated to check for the converters once and then be cached.

My serialization class allows callers to pass in their own custom converters. When this is done I create a new `IContractResolver` that takes these new converters and the default contract resolver. What I do then is, when resolving the contract for a type, I first get a contract from the default contract resolver. When I get it I then check and see if any of the new converters can handle the type. If they can I 'clone' the json contract and replace the converter with the new one (and cache it).

In this cloning is where I set the `ParametrizedConstructor`. I was not doing this originally, as it was marked as deprecated, I set just the `OverrideCreator`. I ran into an issue when deserializing `Tuple`s. I kept getting an error saying there was no constructor for Tuple. I tried using the stock `JsonConvert` to round trip a `Tuple` and it worked perfectly. In looking into why it worked with `JsonConvert` I found it was because when I 'clone' the contract I was not setting the `ParametrizedConstructor`.

Edit 2:

Here is a slimmed example of my contract resolver:

```
class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly Dictionary<Type, JsonContract> contractDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, JsonContract>();
    readonly List<JsonConverter> converters;
    readonly IContractResolver resolverToExtend;

    public MyContractResolver(List<JsonConverter> converters, IContractResolver resolverToExtend)
    {
        this.converters = converters;
        this.resolverToExtend = resolverToExtend;
    }

    public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
    {
        JsonContract contract;
        if (!contractDictionary.TryGetValue(type, out contract))
        {
            contract = resolverToExtend.ResolveContract(type);
            var converter = contract.Converter;
            foreach (var baseConverter in converters)
            {
                if (baseConverter.CanConvert(type))
                {
                    contract = CloneJsonContract(contract, type, baseConverter);
                    break;
                }
            }
            contractDictionary.Add(type, contract);
        }
        return contract;
    }

    static JsonContract CloneJsonContract(JsonContract contract, Type type, JsonConverter customConverter)
    {
        JsonContract newContract;

        // Check contract type and create a new one (JsonArrayContract, JsonDictionaryContract etc)
        if (contract is JsonArrayContract)
        {
            newContract = new JsonArrayContract(type);
        }
        //...
        else
        {
            JsonObjectContract jsonObjectContract = contract as JsonObjectContract;
            if (jsonObjectContract != null)
            {
                newContract = CloneJsonObjectContract(new JsonObjectContract(type), jsonObjectContract);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown JsonContract type: " + contract.GetType() + ", object: " + contract);
            }
        }
        //Copy properties like IsReference, OnSerializingCallbacks etc. and set the new converter
        return newContract;
    }

    static JsonObjectContract CloneJsonObjectContract(JsonObjectContract newContract, JsonObjectContract oldContract)
    {
        newContract.OverrideCreator = oldContract.OverrideCreator;
        newContract.DefaultCreator = oldContract.DefaultCreator;
        newContract.DefaultCreatorNonPublic = oldContract.DefaultCreatorNonPublic;
        newContract.ParametrizedConstructor = oldContract.ParametrizedConstructor; // If I do no copy this then the behavior of the old and new contract is different.
        CloneJsonPropertyList(newContract.Properties, oldContract.Properties);
        CloneJsonPropertyList(newContract.CreatorParameters, oldContract.CreatorParameters);
        return newContract;
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is really a second question now.  You're only doing a shallow clone, not a deep clone, right?  If so, you could use the "dark arts" of reflection and do a `MemberwiseClone()`, similarly to how I clone a `JsonProperty` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155458/json-deserialize-from-legacy-property-names.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] for your "updated" question?  I'm having some problem visualizing your custom contract resolver.

Comment: @dbc added a code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precise function of the two properties [`OverrideCreator`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract_OverrideCreator.htm) and [`ParametrizedConstructor`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract_ParametrizedConstructor.htm)(and its derived delegate property `ParameterizedCreator`) can be seen from the reference source of  [`JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L2250):

1. If there is an `OverrideCreator`, use it to create the object using the `CreatorParameters`.
2. Else if there is a `DefaultCreator` and it is either public or private and [`JsonSerializer.ConstructorHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_ConstructorHandling.htm) says to use it anyway, then use it to create the object.
3. Else if there is a `ParameterizedCreator`, use it to create the object.
4. Otherwise the object cannot be constructed, so throw an exception.

Thus the `OverrideCreator` takes precedence unconditionally while the `ParameterizedCreator` is used as a fallback only when there is no `DefaultCreator` to use instead.  I **suspect** that Newtonsoft marked the latter as obsolete because they want to transition it to being **`internal`**.  I.e. users of Json.NET will always be able to set an *unconditional* override creator but should have no need to set a *conditional* fallback creator that might or might not be called depending on the value of `ConstructorHandling`.

For instance, if you want to inject a creation method for a specific type `T`, you could use the following:

```
public class FactoryContractResolver<T> : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly Func<T> creator;

    public FactoryContractResolver(Func<T> creator)
    {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        if (objectType == typeof(T))
        {
            contract.OverrideCreator = delegate(object[] args) { return creator(); };
            if (contract.CreatorParameters != null)
                contract.CreatorParameters.Clear();
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

Note that the base class [`DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateObjectContract.htm) will not throw an exception if a constructor could not be found.  The exception is only thrown when actually trying to construct an instance of such a type during deserialization.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The move to make it `internal` makes sense the way you lay it out. If that happens though, would it then be impossible to 'clone' a `JsonContract`? I updated my answer to explain what I am doing.