# Having multiple aliases for json property C# deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Using Newtonsoft to (de)serialize Json, I want to refactor a propertyname without existing Json-markup to break.

F.e.:

```
{
  "old-very-specific-property": "value"
}
```

Should work just as fine as:

```
{
  "new-name": "value"
}
```

mapping to

```
public class Model {
  [JsonProperty, JsonRequired]
  public string NewName { get; set; } 
}
```

I want BOTH versions of Json above to map to the provided model, in order to maintain backwards compatibility.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792274/alternate-property-name-while-deserializing/19885911#19885911

Comment: [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915503/net-newtonsoft-json-deserialize-map-to-a-different-property-name)

Comment: See also [json deserialize from legacy property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155458/json-deserialize-from-legacy-property-names).

Comment: entirely forgot I asked the question. But I do like @TimRogers ' answer in dbc 's link best.
Simple private set-only properties, making the backwards compatibility on object level instead of explicitly digging into converters and resolvers.