# Deserialize different JSONs in to one class

Tags: c#, json, serialization

First of all; I'm using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize JSON into objects like this:

JSON:

```
[{"number":22041}]
```

Order Object

```
[JsonProperty("number")]
public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
```

However, depending on which version the 'other' side is on, the Json may change into

```
[{"order_number":22041}]
```

So I'd actually like to pre-define "number" and "order_number" to both deserialize into my OrderNumber.

Is there a way to achieve something like the following (that actually works)

```
[JsonProperty("order_number")]
[JsonProperty("number")]
public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
```

I could write another class that has the same properties but with other JsonProperties depending on the Version they are on, but that seems like something to try last, unless there is no possible way to do this easier.

---

**Update**

I agree that this question is a duplicate of the question above. However since the given keys in the JSON changes significantly, I will be making duplicate objects (OrderV1 , OrderV2 as example).

Simply replacing some characters into other ones will not be enough **in my case**.

Comment: Too bad (or: luckily) that C# doesn't have [unions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union).

Comment: Have you tried using [Obsolete]-marked properties for the older versions that access the newer properties in their setters and getters?

Comment: @UweKeim That would make it easier (or even worse) indeed! ;)

Comment: Or alternatively, use different classes for different API versions, then transform them into the newer class. (You can use Omu.ValueInjector to help with identical properties.)

Comment: you should create a custom JSONConverter trying to match the property name. This answer can give you some idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792274/alternate-property-name-while-deserializing/19885911#19885911

Why don't you convert the JSON to a string, replacing "order_number": to "number":?

Comment: @Giox Thank you! I will give this a shot before!

Comment: In addition to the marked duplicate, there's also [json deserialize from legacy property names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33155458/3744182).